# JavaScript Creating functions for dynamic buttons and inputs

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, element

I have created iX2  buttons and i textboxes with the following code:

```js
function AddIt(){
 
for (var i=1; i < 4; i++) { 

var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var button = document.createElement("button");
var button2 = document.createElement("button");
var input = document.createElement("input");
tr.id= "tr"+[i];
td.id= "td"+[i];

button.id= "BT"+[i];
button.innerHTML = "BT"+[i];
button.name= "BT";
button.classList.add("BT");


button2.id= "BT"+[i]+".1";
button2.innerHTML = "BT"+[i]+".1";
button2.name= "BT2";
button2.classList.add("BT2");


input.id="TB"+[i];
input.style="width:40px"
input.value = "TB"+[i];


var Table = document.getElementsByTagName("Table")[0];
Table.append(tr);
Table.append(td);
td.append(button);
td.append(button2);
td.appendChild(input);
 
};
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add Textbox" onClick="AddIt()">
<table id="Table" name= "Table" cellpadding="5" border="0" >
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

so it creates 2 buttons and 1 textbox in each row of the table

Now I want to add a function for "each button", so that 
the first button of the first row changes the value of the first textbox to  1, and 
the second button of that row, changes the value of the first textbox  to 0. 
and so on.

any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: please create html code or fiddle so we can better understand sir

Comment: Thanks Parth for the comment, I added snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet which inputs the 1/0 to the textboxes.

```js
for (var i=1; i < 4; i++) { 

var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var button = document.createElement("input");
var button2 = document.createElement("input");
var input = document.createElement("input");

button.type="button";
button.id= "BT"+[i];
button.value = "BT"+[i];
button.classList.add("BT");

button2.type="button";
button2.id= "BT"+[i]+".1";
button2.classList.add("BT2");
button2.value ="BT"+[i]+".1";

input.id="TB"+[i];

function assign(textElt){
button.onclick = function(){ textElt.value = 1; }
button2.onclick = function(){ textElt.value = 0; }
}

var Table = document.getElementsByTagName("Table")[0];
Table.append(tr);
Table.append(td);
td.append(button);
td.append(button2);
td.appendChild(input);

assign(input);
};
```

```html
<table>
</table>
```